# Rewriting the quotient of taylor series (to calculate residue)

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, complex-integration

To calculate the residue of a complex integral, I look at the taylor expansion of $ \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$, and want to find the coefficient in front of the $z^{-1}$ term.

I have been given the solution, which is:
$$ \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2}z^2 + \ldots}{z(1 - \frac{1}{6}z^2 + \ldots)} =^{*} \frac{1}{z}(1 - \frac{1}{2}z^2)(1 + \frac{1}{6}z^2) + \ldots = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{3}z + \ldots$$
so the residue is 1.

I can't, however, figure out how he performs the step I've marked with an asterisk (from fraction to no fraction, so to speak). Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know that the order of the pole of $f$ at $a$ is $n$ then $\lim_{z\to a}(n-1)![(z-a)f(z)]^{(n-1)}$. In the case of poles of order $1$ the formula is particularly nice to use $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)$. In your case $\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)/z}=1/1=1$.

Comment: In the case that you really want to divide Taylor series you can just use long division. Take out the factor that vanishes at $z=0$ such that the denominator doesn't vanish at zero. Order the series in increasing order of the exponents, as usual. Apply the long division algorithm, just as you use it for polynomials, to the series. Each step gives you a new term of the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $|w|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1-w}=\sum_{n\geq o}w^n=1+w+o(w).$$
Hence
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{6}z^2+o(z^2)}=1+\frac{1}{6}z^2+o(z^2).$$